# What means OnDemand, LoadAfterUI, Localizable attributes in SharePoint:ScriptLink tag?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-hosted-app, scriptlink

I'm developing simple sharepoint hosted app. on app's default.aspx i see the below scriptlink tag. but i do not understand the need of  **OnDemand, LoadAfterUI, Localizable** attributes.

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
```

Can anyone explain it for me in simple and understandable words. Thank you in advance.